# Will not start after new battery was placed

Tags: honda, battery, starting, accord

My car (1994 Honda accord) is not starting even after I put in a new battery. When I wiggle the Battery a little, I find that the car will turn half way, with the lights showing the battery and oil, the music will come on the electric windows move, yet when I try to start it, everything goes dark, no click. I have just put in a new battery and had a starter put on it. Before it stopped running there was a rubber smell when it got hot, could this be the problem?  Our what?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the connection. You have either not tightened the strap enough, there is something there keeping the electricity from flowing (corrosion), or both. Take both straps off of the battery and ensure they are completely clean. You can do this by using a small brush and water to clean the crud off. Replace the straps on the battery (assuming the battery posts are clean due to it being a new battery) and tighten until they don't wiggle anymore. If available, you could put a small amount of grease (petroleum based) on the posts and on the straps to help prevent corrosion in the future.

If this doesn't work there could be a problem with your one or both of your battery cables. Look for fat spots in the cable. If this is the case, it means you have corrosion inside the cable and it will have to be replaced.